# Xcode 4.2 feature - ARC is it the same as adding the flag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

In xCode 4.2 includes a new "Migrate to Objective-C ARC" tool in the `Edit->Refactor`. So is this same as adding the flag `-fno-objc-arc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's the opposite actually.

The `Mirgrate to Objective-C ARC`-tool goes through the selected files and converts them to ARC-supported files. Adding the `-fno-objc-arc`-flag to a file tells the compiler that the file does not support ARC. This is useful for large frameworks that haven't been updated to support ARC.

Comment: Do you the pros and cons when using these 2 methods

Comment: Well, the mirgration-tool is pretty good, but it can have some errors. It is however a good tool and you should use it if you already have a project which isn't written in `ARC` (if you want to start programming in ARC, of course).
The flag doesn't have any cons as I can see, but it is great for what I described in my answer, using files that haven't been written in ARC in an ARC-enabled project. It is actually the only way you can use these files in ARC-enabled projects.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you clicked the tick next to my answer :)